# Grey canvas of `leaflet` map in the pdf_output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want create leaflet map with some markers. This works well with HTML output, but I also want to send a pdf to some participants who like to have a hard copy.

It works well for html output, but I get a grey canvas around the map in pdf mode. I tried to change `width` and `fig.width` and so on, with no real success.

**Example file `test.Rmd`**

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

## Test RMarkup file

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  setView(lng = 13.7463, lat = 51.0628, zoom = 12) %>%
  addMarkers(lng = 13.7444, lat = 51.06162,
             options = markerOptions(title = "Terence Hill Ice Saloon"))
```
````

**PDF output with grey canvas**

[image: leflet map with grey canvas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `webshot2` to take a a PDF screenshot of the the html map.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

## Test RMarkup file

```{r echo=FALSE}
## load packages
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot2)

m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles %>%
      setView(lng = 13.7463, lat = 51.0628, zoom = 12) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = 13.7444, lat = 51.06162,
             options = markerOptions(title = "Terence Hill Ice Saloon"))

## saves html then screenshots to PDF
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(m, "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("temp.html", file = "m.pdf",
        cliprect = "viewport")
```
````

You could also use `webshot2` to export a PNG file which you then can reference in the .Rmd file.

````
 ---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

## Test RMarkup file

```{r echo=FALSE, }
## load packages
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot2)

m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles %>%
      setView(lng = 13.7463, lat = 51.0628, zoom = 12) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = 13.7444, lat = 51.06162,
             options = markerOptions(title = "Terence Hill Ice Saloon"))

## save html to png
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(m, "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("temp.html", file = "m.png",
        cliprect = "viewport")
```
    
![Terence Hill Ice Saloon, of course](m.png)
````

Comment: Works. Many thanks for the pragmatic workaround. Before accepting, I still leave the question open for potential other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simplier:

**RMD:**

````
---
title: "PIC"
output:
  pdf_document
---
Irgendwo spielte Musik.

\begin{figure}
\centering
```{r, echo = F, warning = F, out.width = '100%'}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  setView(lng = 13.7463, lat = 51.0628, zoom = 12) %>%
  addMarkers(lng = 13.7444, lat = 51.06162,
             options = markerOptions(title = "Terence Hill Ice Saloon"))
```
\end{figure}
````

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Good idea, but did not work on my systems yet: Windows 10, RStudio 2022-07.1, R 4.1.3 and Texlive 2021 or R 4.2.1 and Tinytex. I will try it also on Linux.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I have same version of Rstudio and R 4.1.0. I don't know, what can't work.

Comment: I've now updated all packages and switched to Texlive 2022, but did not get the approach with the enclosing latex environment running. However, after updating everything, including latex, my original code works now without grey canvas, but the picture still occupies a full page with leaflet copyright appears at the bottom of the page. Anyway, I can use the approach of @SEAnalyst.